# Rails authlogic - NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

Im trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.nathancolgate.com/post/184694426/adding-email-and-user-verification-to-authlogic).

Its about adding email confirmation after registration... The thing is when I submit the form I get this error

> NoMethodError in UsersController#create
>
> undefined method
>   `deliver_verification_instructions!'
>   for #

I looked at the code and indeed there is no such a method on my user model... Im very new at rails...Is the tutorial wrong??

Comment: I don't see that method in the page you linked. I do see deliver_verification_instructions!. Can you revise your question to include code?

Comment: where exactly do you see that method defined?.. I just see it being called but not defined.... its supposed to be in the user model...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, tutorial has missed that method in `User` model. It should be something like this instead of `deliver_password_reset_instructions`:

```
def deliver_verification_instructions!
  reset_perishable_token!
  Notifier.deliver_verification_instructions(self)
end
```

I haven't checked that tutorial if rest is OK, but that was wrong for sure

Comment: Yep - NachoF you might want to keep searching for account activation tutorials.